# How do I submit value of a "custom" input in a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm wirting a CRUD application and I ran into this problem today:
There's a form where user can set the entry's priority (basically a number from 1 to 3). But instead of an input with type="number" or anything similar, I created a "custom" input. It's a small circle that changes colors when you click it (colors represent numbers from 1 to 3). My question is: how do I submit this value to the form?

The solution I came up with was to use an input with type="hidden" and before the form is submitted, javascript changes the input's "value" attribute to match the number selected in the "custom" input. This seems to be working but according to MDN type="hidden" inputs are used for "data that cannot be seen or **modified** by users when a form is submitted", so I'm guessing this is not a typical solution to this kind of problem. Is there some kind of agreed upon method for this problmes like this?

Comment: I'm voting to close as this will generate opinions, but this is an acceptable use of the `hidden` type - since the user can't actually change it. You are simply using the hidden field to submit the data.

Comment: Well the user is not modifying it... you are. There might be a better way to do what you want, hard to guess without seeing what you are actually doing. And yes people do use hidden inputs where they set values based on other things. So you are not doing anything wrong.

Comment: Oh, ok. I confused modifying the input itself with action that leads to the input being modified. This makes sense, thanks guys